# Passing Any Type As A Method Parameter with C

Tags: c

I am trying to have a method that can take in ANY TYPE as a parameter (Object1, Object2, etc.). Here is a very simple method to illustrate what it would be trying to do:

```
void printAnything(Object obj) {
    obj.print("hi");
}
```

And what I am asking is, what would replace Object in that method?

Thank you!

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion you are not actually using C.

Comment: I'm using C : I have 2 "objects" which can print text with the print function, but their types are differents

Comment: I rather think that `Object obj` refers to an instance of a class.

Comment: What specific language/platform are you using? What output did you get when you tried to compile that code? You're more likely to get an answer from someone who can reproduce what you saw and respond with a working example.

Comment: Rémi, Doing this with a fixed amount of types is easier than `ANY TYPE`.  As you only have 2 types, perhaps changing the goal from `ANY TYPE` to support the two types of interest and maybe a few more - but `ANY TYPE` is quite broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Passing Any Type As A ... Parameter

```
void f(/* no signature here */);

int main() {
  f(1);
  f(1.2);
  f("Hello");
  f(f);
}

void f(/* TBD signature */) {
  ;
}
```

Calling a function with any type is easy.  Doing something useful with that is the tricky part.

An [example of printing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) with out directly specifying the type using `_Generic()` to steer code.

```
GPrintf("The answer to everything ", GP(42), " or ", GP(42.0), GP_eol);
```

The central idea it to make a function-like macro that uses `_Generic` to selectivity form code.  Below is a square root example.

```
#define xsqrt(X) _Generic((X), \
  long double: sqrtl, \
  default: sqrt, \
  float: sqrtf \
  )(X)


xsqrt(42.0f); // calls  sqrtf
xsqrt(42.0);  // calls  sqrt
xsqrt(42);    // calls  sqrt
```

Comment: Nice ! Thanks !

Comment: @Rémi: Note that this approach works for C 2011 and later - for C99 and earlier, it gets a *lot* messier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.
In C there are no overloads, one function, one name, you'll need to use a type that supports all your needs, e.g. (void *)

Comment: `printf()` takes in all sorts of types without a common type such as `void*` for the data, although it does use `char*` for the format.  The challenging part is 1) how to inform the function how to interpret the parameters (e.g. a format) or 2) how to steer code (e.g. `_Generic`).